# Reoccurring calendar event based on an existing event?

Tags: google-calendar-api

How would I schedule a reoccurring event 10 days before the second Saturday each month in Google Calendar?

Comment: Hey Thomas! Welcome to StackOverflow. I'm not familiar enough with the **Google Calendar API** to answer your question. But it's worth noting that it uses [RFC 5545](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545#section-3.8.5) for defining the recurrence format. If this is possible using a single `RRULE`, it's likely going to require a combination of `BYDAY`, `BYSETPOS`, and possibly `BYMONTHDAY`. Check out the RFP for examples that might point you in the right direction. Otherwise, these keywords might help you find relevant information.

Comment: One other consideration: What is your expected behavior if the second Saturday is the 8th, 9th, or 10th? I assume in that case, you'd still want the recurring event to occur ten days before—even though that would place it in the previous month? Or would you prefer for it to be 10 days before _or_ the first of the month, whichever is _later_?